# How to migrate Lightroom metadata presets to another computer?

Tags: lightroom

I am moving to a new computer and created some metadata presets, see here:

[image]

I want to move those presets (not the data stored in photos!) to the new computer. How do I do that? All online info I could find would only how to store the metadata in the photo, but not how to make the presets available on another computer.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify your OS so here is location for Windows:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Lightroom\Metadata Presets
```

Here you will see list of metadata import presets. For MacOS the path should be something like:

```
/Users/<you username>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Lightroom/Metadata Presets
```

To move them to another computer just copy the files from source machine to target one in the same directory (if LR is run in this moment may be need to restart it)